# Is there any sentiment forum dataset for unsupervised training available?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis, unsupervised-learning

I recently finished a machine learning course and would like to make a forum sentiment analysis tool, to apply it in stock-related forums.

The idea is to:

1. Capture (text mining) users with their comments, and evaluate their comment's sentiment (positive, negative, neutral).
2. Capture what happens (stock market) after those comments, and assign a weight to the user accordingly (bigger weight if the user's sentiments is spot-on and the market follows the same direction)
3. Use the comments as a tool to predict market direction.

Actually, I do this myself (pay attention on forums) plus my own technical analysis and the obligatory due diligence, and it has been working very well for me. I just wanted to try to automate it a little bit and maybe even allow a program to play with some of my accounts (paper trading first, and if it performs decently assign some money in a real account)

This would be my first machine learning project (just as a proof-of-concept) so any comments would be very kindly appreciated.

The biggest problem that I find is that I would like to make an **unsupervised training**, and I need a sample dataset to do the training.

**Is there any known forum-sentiment dataset available to be used for unsupervised training?**

I've found several sentiment datasets (twitter, imbd, amazon reviews) but they are very specific to their niche (short messages, movies, products...) but I'm looking for something more general.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are looking for an unsupervised approach you can use any set of data that matches your "real case scenario". Text mining and sentiment analysis are are often tailored to the problem at hand so it is easy to start directly with the real data. The best approach is to built a scraper that grabs directly the forum posts that you want to analyze. You can build the scraper easily enough with Python (beautifulsoup/selenium). Online is full of nice tutorial eg: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-tutorial-python/

Comment: Thank you; I don't have problems scrapping data from websites; my problem is on how to assign each comment a valid sentiment value (positive, negative, neutral) so that I can use that data set to do an unsupervised training.

Comment: @PtolomeoXII If need to assign a positive/negative/neutral label to each comment, aren't you actually doing supervised learning?

Comment: I'm sorry Ptolomeo, probably i misunderstood your question, but I agree with Darren,  If you are looking to assign a lab to each sample of your dataset you are looking for a supervised approach. 
In unsupervised learning you don't need the labels of the data.